# xUnit - How to select a single Theory when executing from dotnet test CLI

Tags: .net, testing, traits, xunit, dotnet-test

Say I have a test:

```
  [Theory]
  [InlineData("one")]
  [InlineData("two")]
  public void ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest(string s)
  {
      Assert.True(true);
  }
```

I want to execute just the test with Theory data = "one" from the command line using `dotnet test...`. Is this possible?

I know we can select tests using Traits, but I cannot see how to associate a single trait with each single line of Theory data.

As a workaround I thought maybe I could use the technique of [dynamically skipping tests](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/main/DynamicSkipExample), but still to do that I'd need to read an argument from the command line and can't see how to do that either. One workaround to that, might be to set an environment variable on the command line, then run the tests using the dynamic skipping pattern, where the dynamic skip logic would read the command line argument. But that is very clunky.

Comment: You can always split into two tests. To avoid duplication you can wrap test with the method and call it in both tests. Then you will be able to run test based on it's name from command line

Comment: Thanks Fabio that'd work well for small cases. Unfortunately in my case there are hundreds of tests, and the Theory data is being provided by a class which dynamically produces many 10s of rows of data (Browser/OS combinations). I tried to simplify the problem for posting here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`--filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details) parameter of `dotnet test`.

First of all use `-t|--list-tests` to see the test names, then you will get something like:

```bash
dotnet test -t
```

```
The following Tests are available:
    xUnitSkip.UnitTest1.ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest(s: "one")
    xUnitSkip.UnitTest1.ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest(s: "two")
```

Then you can use this information to filter on the `DisplayName`.

Was not able to figure out how to escape double quotes and parenthesis in the name so used "workaround" to combine filtering on `FullyQualifiedName` and `DisplayName`:

```bash
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest&DisplayName~one"
```

Which gives me the following output:

> Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: < 1 ms - xUnitSkip.dll (net7.0)

Compared to one without filter:

> Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     2, Skipped:     0, Total:     2, Duration: 4 ms - xUnitSkip.dll (net7.0)

**UPD**

Was able to figure out the double quotes escaping, so parameter names can be used - replace double quotes with `%22`:

```bash
dotnet test --filter "DisplayName~s: %22one%22"
```

**UPD2**

Courtesy of [@Jan Zakrzewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14448398/jan-zakrzewski):

Parenthesis can be escaped by using `\` i.e. `\(` and `\)`.

Which makes the full filter looking like the following:

```
dotnet test --filter "DisplayName=xUnitSkip.UnitTest1.ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest\(s: %22two%22\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could separately run tests using `XUnit Traits` i.e. something like that

```cs
  [Trait("Category", "one")]
  [Theory]
  [InlineData("one")]
  public void ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest(string s)
  {
      myTestImpl(s);
  }

  [Trait("Category", "two")]
  [Theory]
  [InlineData("two")]
  public void ShouldSelectSingleTheoryFromDotnetTest(string s)
  {
      myTestImpl(s);
  }

  private void myTestImpl(string s)
  {
      Assert.True(true);
  }
```

to run only tests for "one" inline data - `dotnet test --filter Category=one` and for second - `dotnet test --filter Category=two`

Comment: You don't need categories for this, you can filter just by test name.

Comment: Categories are more convenient than filters, at least because you could rename test function name and inline data, with categories you don't need to change cmd line to run tests

Comment: While I completely agree with the general approach (personally extensively use categories) in this particular case I don't see any major advantages.