# What is the correct syntax to filter an XUnit test with specific inline data using the dotnet test command?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, inline, xunit

I am trying to apply a `--filter` when calling XUnit tests with `dotnet test`. The goal is to retry some specific test cases with values in the `InlineData` attribute.

For example:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, 2, 3)]
[InlineData(2, 2, 4)]
public void TestMethod(int param1, int param2, int expectedResult)
{
    var actualResult = param1 + param2;
    actualResult.Should().Be(expectedResult);
}
```

The trx log file shows the test cases with inline data in this form:

`Application.Tests.TestClass.TestMethod(param1: 1, param2: 2, expectedResult: 3)`
`Application.Tests.TestClass.TestMethod(param1: 2, param2: 2, expectedResult: 4)`

I also see this same form in the test list if I run `dotnet test "testassembly" -t`

I attempted to apply the filter for the 2,2,4 case with:
`dotnet test "testassembly" --filter "FullyQualifiedName=Application.Tests.TestClass.TestMethod\(param1: 2, param2: 2, expectedResult: 4\)"`

This does not match any tests. A similar technique works with MSTest but I can't seem to find the correct syntax for XUnit.

I can match the test if I omit the inline data parameter values and then it runs the test with all combinations of the inline data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xUnit - How to select a single Theory when executing from dotnet test CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65885019/xunit-how-to-select-a-single-theory-when-executing-from-dotnet-test-cli)

Comment: I think that is probably the answer. I've moved off that task long ago so can't really try it out now. We were trying this as part of a test case retry script. xUnit has a retry attribute which made all this irrelevant anyway.