# List of tests in the project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest, xunit

I am writing a small C# project that will count the coverage of all tests individually in a project with tests C#. To do this, I need to get a list of all the tests in the project in the *FullyQualifiedName* format, which can then be passed to the `--filter` parameter for the `dotnet test` command. What is the easiest way to do this?

I was hoping that the `dotnet test -t(or --list-tests)` command would help me, but it only outputs the names of the methods, without specifying which path they are on, and this information is not enough to run each test individually

I've seen a solution for the NUnit framework https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/discussions/897, but I need it for MSTest and for Xunit

Comment: So you want a code coverage report for each individual unit test? Might I inquire to what purpose? I have some difficulty understanding how it would be useful.

Comment: Are you just trying to replicate what [Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) does?

Comment: By using command-line or doing it programmatically?

Comment: @JonasH this is part of a utility designed to run only those tests that depend on current changes in the project

Comment: @DavidG can coverlet collect the coverage for each test separately?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub It doesn't matter to me
I considered the option of loading the project assembly and searching for all methods with the necessary annotation, but I worry that this option may not always work due to the features of the framework unknown to me (for example, there may be different annotations marking the method as a test)

Comment: VS has some support for [Live Unit Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing?view=vs-2022). If you want to provide some equivalent functionality you probably need some fairly in depth knowledge of roslyn and xUnit. If you are not careful there is a risk that calculating what tests need to be re-run takes longer than just re-running them.

Comment: @JonasH Why would I want to know Roslyn? It seems that having received a list of all the tests, I can individually run them with coverage calculation using coverlet and save this information (well, update it when changing tests or adding new ones). And then look at the intersection of changes in the project and the coverage of each test, and if it is not empty, then run the test. It is clear that it will take a long time to work the first time, but in the future it should work faster than running all the tests

Comment: The live Unit testing feature presumably integrates with the compiler and the incremental build system to monitor code changes. If you are making something external you might not need that. But just checking if source files has changed sounds challenging to make work reliably and fast,  what about changes to dependencies? changes to the tests? Or to the build system?

Comment: @JonasH thank you for reminding me about changing dependencies, I didn't think about it, but in the projects for which my utility is being developed, dependencies and build systems don't change so often and I think it will be possible to track and restart all tests

Comment: `dotnet test -t` worked just fine for me - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76328083/2501279). Also for xunit some magic can be done programmatically - like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77860011/2501279).

Comment: @GuruStron I want solution for any framework. `dotnet test -t` doesn't work with MSTest(it show only method names). Second option work only with xunit

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Xunit using this https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/542

```cs
string dllPath = "...";
Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
        
var controller = new XunitFrontController(AppDomainSupport.Denied, dllPath);
using var visitor = new TestDiscoverySink();
controller.Find(false, visitor, TestFrameworkOptions.ForDiscovery());
visitor.Finished.WaitOne();
var tests = visitor.TestCases.Select(testCase => testCase.DisplayName).ToList(); 
visitor.Finished.Dispose();
```

It doesn't work for MSTest

There is also a problem that due to `Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath)`, the assembly file is blocked