# Is there anyway to get the total numbers of tests in xunit?

Tags: c#, testing, count, xunit

Is there anyway to get the total numbers of tests in xunit?

I know i can run the tests and get the value that way, but I just want to run a command to get the total amount of tests in my framework for reporting purposes without having to run the full suite to get the value. Xunit. C#

Comment: You can run `dotnet test -t -v=q` (`-t` - short for `--list-tests` and `-v=q` sets the verbosity to quiet) and process the output

Comment: excellent, thanks! It hasn't given me a summary, but that's ok. I can parse the output. Thanks!

Comment: Was glad to help! Will add as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection.
Every test in `xunit` is marked as `[fact]` or `[theory]`

```
// You should load the assembly containing your tests. Replace "YourTestAssembly.dll" with the path to your actual test assembly.
        var testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("YourTestAssembly.dll");
        
        // Get all types from the assembly
        var testTypes = testAssembly.GetTypes();
        
        // Count all methods with Fact or Theory attributes
        var testMethodsCount = testTypes.SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
                                        .Count(method => method.GetCustomAttributes<FactAttribute>().Any() 
                                                      || method.GetCustomAttributes<TheoryAttribute>().Any());
```

Comment: I had tried this already, but i don't think it accounts for parameterized tests. e.g. I could have only 1 Theory decorator, but could have 6 parameters (6 individual tests).

Comment: you could include InlineDataAttribute , and in foreach just replace inline data with results of TheoryAttribute. That would get you closer to actual result.

Comment: @J.Memisevic but this is not guaranteed still - you can have test data provided by method. See my answer, xUnit infrastructure can be utilized, or just `dotnet test`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some extra post-processing you can use [`dotnet test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) with `-t` option:

> `-t|--list-tests`
> List the discovered tests instead of running the tests.

```bash
dotnet test -t -v=q
```

This will result in listing all the tests in the target (project, solution, etc) like the following:

```
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.8.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following Tests are available:
    SomeTest
    SomeTestWithParam(True,True)
```

Which you can parse and count the output lines.

Also you can do it programmatically explicitly for xUnit (based on [this sample from the docs](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/3f55e554e7de7eb2cd9802fa9e73a706520646cd/TestRunner/Program.cs) using [`xunit.runner.utility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.utility) nuget):

```
ManualResetEvent finished = new(false);
// for my repro added unit test as project reference
// and used type from the project to find assembly
using var ar = AssemblyRunner.WithoutAppDomain(
    Path.GetFileName(typeof(TestAssemblyLandmark).Assembly.Location));

ar.OnDiscoveryComplete += info =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(info.TestCasesDiscovered);
    finished.Set();
    ar.Cancel();
};

ar.Start();
finished.WaitOne();
```