# How to use dotnet CLI in CSharp code not through processes?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nuget, dotnet-cli

I want to use the dotnet utility commands in the C# code, for example, to get a list of all the tests in the project or run the entire test project. At the same time, I want not just wrappers over console commands, but the code of the utility itself. Because sometimes console commands do not output everything that is necessary. I was hoping there was a nuget package with all this code, but I couldn't find it.

I've seen the Microsoft library.DotNet.Client.Utils but if I understood correctly, then this is just a wrapper over the console utility and does not suit me. I also saw the code https://github.com/dotnet/sdk?tab=readme-ov-file, which I understand contains what I need, but I don't understand how to connect it as a nuget package to the project

Comment: TBH it is not very clear what is your problem, the question is too broad to answer. _"Because sometimes console commands do not output everything that is necessary. "_ - do you have a [mre]? Also please check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/77858873/2501279 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/65885019/2501279 maybe they will give you some useful pointers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GuruStron I want to find and use the code that runs with the `dotnet test` command

Comment: @MaratTim what do you mean by "runs with the dotnet test command"

Comment: @GuruStron I'm sorry, I was referring to the `dotnet test -t` command. When I downloaded dotnetsdk, I got the dotnet command in the PATH. I want to find the code that runs when the `dotnet test -t` command is run in the console

Comment: _"but I don't understand how to connect it as a nuget package to the project"_ - why do you want that exactly? AFAIK those parts are not distributed as nuget packages.